# Flask Blueprint Subdomain Not Working GAE

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-app-engine

I have an application deployed to Google App Engine (GAE) using `Flask in a Python 3 Standard Environment`, which is working fine. Now, I want to have a subdomain, but I don't want to create a new service for that, as it increases (front-end instance) costs. In my local host I have been able to do it by using [Flask Blueprint subdomains](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html), however in my production application, that is not working.

Consider that my application has the following custom DNS configured: `example.com`, and `admin.example.com`. This is what I have defined in my application:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(admin, subdomain='admin')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'
    app.run()
```

My dispatch.yaml looks like this:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*.example.com/*"
    service: default
```

When I execute locally, I get the expected behavior:

- Accessing `example.com` points me to `app` home page
- Accessing `admin.example.com` points me to `admin` home page

However, in production (GAE) both URLs, point to the `app` home page.

I've not been able to find much information on this topic. Any hints/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It turns out that the order matters. This is how I fixed it:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'

app.register_blueprint(admin, subdomain='admin')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```